# Using pointers to return char and float values from scanf back to main function C

Tags: c

I don't quite understand why the pointer passes the value from the scanf from info function to the main function but the function I just define in the info function does not pass back to the main function. Do I need the do while loop to achieve the goal of making sure the user inputs a value for a b and c?

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void info (char *a, char *b, char *c);

    void main(void)
    {
        char lett1 = 'a', lett2 = 'b', lett3 = 'c';
        info (&lett1, &lett2, &lett3);
        printf("\n The characters chosen are: %c, %c and %c", lett1, lett2, lett3);
    }

    void info (char *a, char *b, char *c)
    {
        a = 'E';
        printf("\n Type any 2 characters then press enter:  "); 
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf(" %c", b);
        do{
            scanf(" %c", c);
        }while (c == NULL);
    }
```

The second piece of code is where I am also using pointer and scanf but I can't get the programme to work. When I use the sections I have commented out, (type = 'A' or type = 'B') it works but not with the scanf. Furthermore, the value defined in input function is never moved to the main function.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    void input (char *type, float *BU_Dist, float *SC_Dist, float *DC_Dist);

    void main (void)
    {
        char type_M = 'Z';
        float BU_Dist_M, SC_Dist_M, DC_Dist_M;
        input (&type_M, &BU_Dist_M, &SC_Dist_M, &DC_Dist_M);
        printf("Value back in the main is %c", type_M);
    }

    void input (char *type, float *BU_Dist, float *SC_Dist, float *DC_Dist)
    {
        printf("Which car type (A/B):");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c", type);
        //type = 'A'
        //type = 'C';
        printf ("%c \n\n", type);
        if(type == 'A'|| type == 'B'||type == 'a'||type == 'b') { 
        printf("\nGreat! &c selected! \n", type);
        }else{
        type = 'A';
        printf("\nInvalid value selected, type has been defaulted to %c \n", type);
        }
    }
```

Any help understanding how both pointers and scanf work together when in function other than the main one would be much appriecated. Thanks

Comment: In the first code-snippet, `a = 'E';` is wrong, `a` is a *pointer* to a character and you need to *dereference* it using the `*` operator to get what it points to. E.g. `*a = 'E'`. A good compiler should warn about this. Then calling `fflush` with an input-only stream like `stdin` is explicitly mentioned in the C specification as *undefined behavior*. Also the loop will iterate once only, as `c` will *never* be a null pointer. For input validation using [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) you have to check what it *returns*.

Comment: As for your question about the pointers and how passing pointers to variables as arguments to a function, do some searching and research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: `void main`, `fflush(stdin)` - both wrong. Also read the manual page for `scanf`

Comment: BTW - The convention is capital letters for macros, lowercase otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the commented section you are assigning char value to a `char*` resulting in undefined behavior.

Also in this code also you do `type='A'` which is basically not covered as code didnt go to else part I suppose.

If you want to assign you will do it like this `*type='A'`.

For comparison you need to dereference the `char*` to get the value.

```
if(*type == 'A'|| *type == 'B'||*type == 'a'||*type == 'b') {
```

Also `fflush()` is meant to be used over output stream not input stream. What you did invokes undefined behavior.